# German 10 zehn heller

Tags: economy, money, austria

This 10 zehn heller , which I believe at the top on the reverse says "Notgeld" but it is really hard to make out.

The date looks like "1827" but is probably 1923 and it seems to have a wood grain texture to it. Can anyone give me more information on this piece?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a piece of Notgeld from Austria. A little catalogue can be [found here](http://doris.ooe.gv.at/themen/geschichte/notgeld_view.aspx?gemcan=11101) or [here](http://banknoteindex.com/browse.mhtml?browseBy=Set%20Name&browse=Zell%20Bei%20Zellhof%20O.%C3%96.%20Prv.%20Ludwig%20Altzinger%201).
At that link you find pictures like this:

> [image]
>   [image]

It is indeed made of wood and now quite [scarce to find](https://www.vcoins.com/en/stores/ephesus_numismatics/56/product/austria_wood_notgeld_zell_bei_zellhof_private_ludwig_altzinger__50_pfennig/558241/Default.aspx).
The "made of wood" is emphasised if the full transcript is readable:

> Obverse:  10 Heller
>   Reverse: Notgeld – des – Ludwig Altzinger – Holzindustrieller  – Zell bei Zellhof – anno 1920

The type of wood seems [veneer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_veneer). More general background for the financial and economic situation of and in Austria shortly after the war is at [Notgeld 1918–1924](http://www.geldschein.at/notgeld/notgeld1918.html). *Heller* is the 100th part of the official currency [*Krone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_krone) during the Habsburg monarchy, backed by gold. These pieces were issued locally by an 'industrialist in wood' (Holzindustrieller) who had an ample supply of wood in [Zell (now Bad Zell)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Zell).

Inflation in Austria began much earlier than in Germany. In Austria the value of the Krone went down from the start of the war and inflation reached 1500% by the end of the war compared to 1914 (officially the German Mark just had a rate of 200% up to 1918). This type of money was in official circulation until October, 1st 1921, but lost any real world value before that date.

Comment: Wow!  thank you again for the information. I am learning much history which is most enjoyable, although it was bad news during those times.

Comment: Thank you,   My mother collected German pieces and related. Mother had passed away 5 years ago, and I have these that I posted because I was unable to find information on them. I have others, but was able to find information about them online. I really do appreciate all of your help.  Thank you

Comment: I do have two pieces that looks like certificates, but are not currency. They are also German and were during world war ll .  At the top of both of them, it says:  "  Adolf Hitler Spende der deutschen Wirtschaft. . One is dated June 1941 and the other is June 1942

Comment: I just realized there were more papers hidden behind them. They look like ration stamps that are in German, but I am not certain.